# Running upsert queries in parallel takes a lot of time in postgres

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I'm running 50 parallel containers which ingesting rows to postgres, each container has one connection to postgres.

In the first half an hour, each insert query takes about 200 ms.
After half an hour, the queries become really slow and take about 5-8 seconds.

The query I use to insert (~100 rows each time):

```
INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name(id, source, field3)
VALUES 
(value1, value2, value3),
(value1, value2, value),
...
ON CONFLICT (id, source) DO UPDATE
SET field3 = excluded.field3;
```

I use:

```
self.conn.autocommit = True
```

Also when I run  `SELECT * from pg_stat_activity;` I don't see any stuck queries.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the criteria for a query to be 'stuck'? Please show us the data from pg_stat_activity using its own terminology, not your interpretation of it.  For example, how many of each wait_event show up for the client backends.

Comment: What indexes are on the table? If you stop the jobs and start them again (without truncating away the existing data), do they start out fast?